# How to redirect some actions to another controller in mvc routes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have mvc actions defined in the controllers `TasksController` and `TasksGridViewController`. If the URL `Tasks/Index` or `Tasks/GridView` is called, MVC should look up the action in the `TasksGridViewController`, for all other actions it should use the `TasksController`.

I tried the following route for the action `Index`, but it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "GridViewController/Index",
   url: "{controller}/Index",
   defaults: new
   {
       controller = "{controller}GridView",
       action = "Index"
   });
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You could define those 2 specific routes **BEFORE** the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GridViewController_Index_Action",
    url: "Tasks/Index",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "TasksGridView",
        action = "Index"
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GridViewController_GridView_Action",
    url: "Tasks/GridView",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "TasksGridView",
        action = "GridView"
    }
);

// Now comes the default route:
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Comment: In your solution, you have removed the {controller} placeholders, which is not what I meant. I have several controllers with the same pattern as SomeNameName.cs and {SomeName}GridView.cs. For all of these controllers the Index and GridView action should be redirected to the {SomeName}GridViewController.cs. If I don't use the {controller} placeholder it works, but I don't want to define dozens of routes. I would like to define a route where I can use the current controllername (e.g. {controller}).

Comment: Oh in this case you might need to write a custom route.